# I have a problem to create entities with my tables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi i'm new with Spring Boot and I don't know how to represent my two foreign keys can someone help me to understand.

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id_user INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE email
(
    id_email INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    object VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    message VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    id_sender INT NOT NULL,
    id_recipient INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_sender) REFERENCES user(id_user),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_recipient) REFERENCES user(id_user),
)
```

How to represent the Foreign key relation :/

Answer (score 0):

In your email entity class

```
 @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_sender", referencedColumnName = "id_user")
 private User Id_Sender;
```

@JoinColumn annotation is the key and it will tell this email entity is the owner of the field and reference to the Entity User with column id_user